# issue in Sping integration mail idle inbound adapter

Tags: email, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

we use int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter to fetch emails from ALIYUN emailBox. the spring integration version is 5.3.1.
The adapter config as follows:

```
    <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="mailAdapter"
                                    store-uri="imaps://XXX%40weikayun.com:***@imap.mxhichina.com/INBOX"
                                    channel="InboundChannel"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    should-delete-messages="false"
                                    should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                                    search-term-strategy="unseenSearchTermStrategy"
                                    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
                                    simple-content="true">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="4" fixed-rate="30000"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The javaMailProperties config as follows:

```
    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imaps.timeout">300000</prop>
</util:properties>
```

but recently, we always get "FolderClosedException" exceptions as follows:

```
ImapIdleChannelAdapter: - error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3199) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3043) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:2995) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:197) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:249) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]

ImapIdleChannelAdapter: - Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure in 'idle' task. Will resubmit.
at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:295) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:249) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3199) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:3043) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.idle(IMAPFolder.java:2995) ~[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/:1.5.5]
at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:197) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:277) ~[spring-integration-mail-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
... 10 more
```

after that, no emails can be fetched from emailBox until we restart related process flow, it will just fetch one batch of emails and stopped again.

we also open the mail debug log, in exceptional scenario, there are several unseen emails in emailbox, but adapter cannot fetch them, the searching result [UNSEEN 0], the full logs as following:

```
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPProtocol noop
A279 NOOP
A279 OK NOOP completed
A280 LIST "" INBOX
* LIST () "/" "INBOX"
A280 OK LIST completed
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
* 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UNSEEN 0]
* OK [UIDNEXT 0] Predicted next UID.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY ] UIDs valid.
* FLAGS (\Answered \Seen \Deleted \Draft \Flagged)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Seen \Deleted \Draft \Flagged)] Limited.
A281 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
A282 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH
A282 OK SEARCH completed
A283 IDLE
+ idling
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
```

After restarting the related flow, the unseen emails will be fetched successfully. the searching result [UNSEEN 8], the full logs as following:

```
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 OK LOGIN completed
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 IDLE XLIST UIDPLUS ID SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=EXTERNAL
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: EXTERNAL
A3 LIST "" INBOX
* LIST () "/" "INBOX"
A3 OK LIST completed
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A4 SELECT INBOX
* 18127 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UNSEEN 8]
* OK [UIDNEXT 564053] Predicted next UID.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 2] UIDs valid.
* FLAGS (\Answered \Seen \Deleted \Draft \Flagged)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Seen \Deleted \Draft \Flagged)] Limited.
A4 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
A5 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH 18120 18121 18122 18123 18124 18125 18126 18127
A5 OK SEARCH completed
A6 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
* SEARCH 18120 18121 18122 18123 18124 18125 18126 18127
A6 OK SEARCH completed
A7 FETCH 18120:18127 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODYSTRUCTURE)
......
```

any idea about this issue ? this issue is invoked by email server or spring integration config error ? could anyone give some advice ?

Comment: `Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?`  - any chances to understand from server side why they drop a connection? May they want some specific behavior from us, but we don't support it? Looks like we call an `idle()` on the folder after checking its `isOpen()` state and they drop a connection when `handleIdle()` is performed in Java Mail Client.

Comment: As shown in the email debug log above, our searchStrategy is unseen strategy, but in exceptional scenario, there are unseen emails in emailbox, but adapter cannot fetch them, the searching result [UNSEEN 0].    So for the setting "search-term-strategy" in adapter, is there a good recommendation or any point we should pay attention to ?

Comment: I’m not sure how search is related to folder closed. Feels like unrelated concerns...